# R: Add/duplicate rows to a dataframe and replace column values when condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes named TableA and TableB (reproducible example below).

Within TableA$D, whenever the value is NA, I would like to do two things:

1.) Add/duplicate the relevant rows "n" times, where "n" is defined by how many rows are in TableB.

2.) With the rows duplicated, replace the "NA"'s in TableA$D with the values from TableB.

Sometimes TableB will have 7 values, sometimes 100, and there is no prior knowledge of what values will appear in TableB.

```
A <- c("foo", "foo bar", "foo bar", "bar")
B <- c("bar", "foo", "bar bar", "foo")
C <- c("foo", "foo", "foo", "foo")
D <- c("X", NA, "X", NA)

TableA <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
TableB <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

I am trying to make like the result to look like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | bar | foo | 1 |
| foo | bar | foo | 2 |
| foo | bar | foo | 3 |
| foo | bar | foo | 4 |
| foo | bar | foo | 5 |
| foo | bar | foo | 6 |
| foo | bar | foo | 7 |
| foo bar | foo | foo | X |
| foo bar | bar bar | foo | 1 |
| foo bar | bar bar | foo | 2 |
| foo bar | bar bar | foo | 3 |
| foo bar | bar bar | foo | 4 |
| foo bar | bar bar | foo | 5 |
| foo bar | bar bar | foo | 6 |
| foo bar | bar bar | foo | 7 |
| bar | foo | bar | X |

I have tried following this example [Add values to dataframe when condition met in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997207/add-values-to-dataframe-when-condition-met-in-r) however the logic used doesn't quite seem to fit my scenario.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: NA in tableA are replaced with X in your expected output, I'm not sure I understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be doing what you want. Due to the for-loops, it will be slow but this is the easiest way I found.

```
A <- c("foo", "foo bar", "foo bar", "bar")
B <- c("bar", "foo", "bar bar", "foo")
C <- c("foo", "foo", "foo", "foo")
D <- c("X", NA, "X", NA)
TableA <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
TableB <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
collector<-data.frame()
lTableB<-dim(TableB)[1]
for (i in 1:dim(TableA)[1])
{
  print(i)
  tmp<-TableA[i,]
  repet<-ifelse(is.na(TableA$D[i]), lTableB, 1 )
  for (j in 1:repet) {
    tmp$D<-ifelse(repet>1, j, tmp$D)
    collector<-rbind(collector, tmp)
    }
}
collector
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Frank. It's very close to what I am after -- one thing I am trying to work around is an instance where TableB contains characters (since I can't be sure the values will always be numbers). 

For example, TableB might be c("ABC",2,3,4,5,6,7). If that were to be the input, I don't think the 2nd loop returns what I would like to see.

Comment: Sorry, as soon as I pressed enter I realised how I can work around the problem I just raised... instead of ```tmp$D<-ifelse(repet1>1, j, tmp$D``` I can make it ```tmp$D<-ifelse(repet1>1, TableB[j,] , tmp$D```